# Mixture of textbox and textarea in layout

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to get the following layout in which I visualised in Microsoft Word.

[image]

Right now I had something like:

[image]

I'm having issue with the "Summary" row behaving weirdly when it is followed by a textarea instead. I wanted it to be exactly as the first image layout.

```css
select {
    width: 10%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "input_field">
        <select id = "d1" name = "Name">
            <option value = "name">Name</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "text" id = "name_in">
    </div>
    <div class = "input_field">
        <select id = "d2" name = "Summary">
            <option value = "summ">Summary</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id = "summ_in"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class = "input_field">
        <select id = "d3" name = "Class">
            <option value = "cls">Class</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "text" id = "class_in">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can use css `grid` to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a vertical align to the text area so that it aligns to the top of the line

```css
select {
    width: 10%;
}

textarea {
    vertical-align:top; // Added
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "input_field">
        <select id = "d1" name = "Name">
            <option value = "name">Name</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "text" id = "name_in">
    </div>
    <div class = "input_field">
        <select id = "d2" name = "Summary">
            <option value = "summ">Summary</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id = "summ_in"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class = "input_field">
        <select id = "d3" name = "Class">
            <option value = "cls">Class</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "text" id = "class_in">
    </div>
</body>
```